# Looping Through a JSON array with jQuery to appendTo an HTML div?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working on a personal project, and had a question regarding jQuery and using it to loop through a JSON array.

I have the following JSON array:

```
var thumbDir = [
'"https://www.location.com/1.jpg"',
'"https://www.location.com/2.jpg"', 
'"https://www.location.com/3.jpg"'
];
```

This array will have the locations for the thumbnail images for the homepage. I want to loop through them with jQuery and `appendTo` the following:

```
<div id="thumbContainer"></div>
```

I thought I had it figured out, with the following code, but it's not working, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.each(thumbDir, function(index, value){
                    $("#thumbContainer").appendTo('<img src=' + value + ' height="120" width="172">');
            });
```

I'm pretty new to this, and it's my first project, so I'm just learning as I go. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: go to jQuery API and look up what `appendTo` does. You want `append`

Comment: @EvoD not the issue. `$('element').appendTo('target')` will append 'element' to 'target'. Since you want to add imgs to the div, you need to use `$('target').append('element')`

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) when you should be using [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#thumbContainer").append('img src=' + value + ' height="120" width="172">');
```

Also, I'm assuming you simply omitted the ending brace/parenthesis.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c5kozmaq/

Answer (score 1):

use append instead of appendTo.